# Does GIMP use mozjpeg?

Tags: gimp, jpeg

If I use GIMP and look at different quality settings for JPEG compression, does this reflect (or, roughly match) the encoding efforts of mozjpeg?  (E.g. the claimed ["5% on average" improvement over libjpeg](https://research.mozilla.org/2014/07/15/mozilla-advances-jpeg-encoding-with-mozjpeg-2-0/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  At least, not as of 2017.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/1039